# GPS module IM131227001 only logging

Tags: raspbian, gps, modules

i buy [RPI GPS Add-on IM131227001](http://www.rlx.sk/en/raspberry-pi/2219-raspberry-pi-gps-add-on-itead-im131227001.html) and when i connect it into RPI then GPS module start logging this:

```
May  8 13:57:53 raspi kernel: [  554.811792] SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) debug(g) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) show-blocked-tasks(w)
```

and I can not do anything.

**How I can turn off this logging?**

Comment: This one: http://imall.iteadstudio.com/development-platform/raspi/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works on my [Raspberry Pi Model B](http://raspberrypiaustralia.com.au/products/raspberry-pi-model-b) with [ITead Studio RPI GPS Add-on](http://raspberrypiaustralia.com.au/collections/crusts-add-ons/products/raspberry-pi-gps-add-on)

[image]

## Enable the UART

By default the UART is enabled to allow you to connect a terminal window and login. You need to disable this to free it up for the GPS Module.

**cmdline**

Edit the boot options to change the UART so it doesn't provide a terminal connection by default:

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Change:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

To:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

(you are removing this bit:)

```
console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200
```

**inittab**

Change inittab so it doesn't spawn a login to the serial connection:

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

Change:

```
#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

To:

```
#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

## Reboot

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

## Install GPSD

GPSD is an open source project which provides a daemon which streams GPS data via a TCP socket, allowing you to communicate with a whole host of different GPS devices (not only this one):

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
```

## Run gpsd

GPSD needs to be started up, using the following command:

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

## Test gpsd

There is a simple GPS client which you can run to test everything is working:

```
cgps -s
```

It may take a few seconds for the data to come through.

[image: cgps]

## Troubleshooting

**Baud rate**

If cgps repeatedly times out try running debug mode in the foreground:

```
sudo gpsd -b -N -D 3 /dev/ttyAMA0 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

My GPS's specifications has it's baud rate at 38400 and only starts working after gpsd attempts 4800, 9600, 19200 then finally 38400.

Set baud rate, based on your GPS specs

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 38400
```

(after reboot, baud rate returns to default)

**Don't wait**

Some GPS models require you to use the -n option, which instructs gpsd not to wait for client connection to poll the GPS.

```
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```